# Difference between PROC REG , PROC GLM, and GENMOD

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, multivariate-analysis, sas

Can anyone give me a very simple explanation of each? I have no previous statistical background - what would be examples to use each?

Thank you. Apologies if this is very broad but I cannot decipher the SAS documentation and thought to ask here since some might be famailiar with the software.

Answer (score 1):

PROC REG: REGression

PROC GLM: General Linear Model (not "Generalized", though)

PROC REG and PROC GLM use Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) to solve the equation. However, GLM is broader than PROC REG and can solve more types of equations. GLM models can have non-linear relationships as long as they are additively linear: Y = a + b + c. This does not include transformations (unless you do it manually).

PROC GLM can also be used to conduct ANOVAs, ANCOVAs, MANOVAs, weighted regressions, and polynomial regressions, to name a few.

PROC GENMOD: GENeralized linear MODel (not the best procedure name!)

PROC GENMOD is even broader than GLM. (The person who coined "Generalized Linear Models" regretted the choice of words as it's confusing.[https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-18/issue-1/A-Conversation-with-John-Nelder/10.1214/ss/1056397489.full]) Generalized linear models can include non-linear transformations, like the logistic transformation (which is also covered in PROC LOGISTIC). It can also account for non-constant variances across groups.

REG
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect001.htm

GLM
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect001.htm

GENMOD
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_genmod_sect002.htm

According to the first link, SAS also has other specialized regression procedures: CATMOD, LOGISTIC, MIXED, NLIN, ORTHOREG, PROBIT, RSREG, and TRANSREG. LOGISTIC is for logistic regression, MIXED is for linear mixed effects (some of which can be done with GLM). The others I'm not as familiar with and may be worth reading about for special cases.

You can spend a lot of time with GLM, never use the others, and still have good analyses. Personally, I haven't used REG a lot. GENMOD is great but there are other PROCs that are more specific (e.g., LOGISTIC). MIXED is definitely worth it, but mixed linear models are tricky. I'd recommend doing some reading on them generally so you have an idea when it is useful.

Answer (score -1):

Off the cuff,

PROC REG is a standard linear regression. The other two seem to 'generalized linear regression' approaches, which is what you use when your dependent ("outcome") variable isn't normally distributed.